# Emberjs: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute

Tags: node.js, ember.js

[image]

I'm trying run an Ember project locally : https://github.com/cosmicjs/ember-real-estate-website?files=1.  I'm using pycharm 2017 using git-bash as my terminal in win7. I have npm and node installed along with the jetbrains emberjs plugin.

I can start the server using :

```
  $ COSMIC_BUCKET=your-bucket-slug npm start

  > cosmicrealestate@1.0.0 start E:\ember-real-estate-website
  > node server.js
```

When I open the browser I see nothing. In the console:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-969213113bf8ce8653053cf775905b0d.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'X3XPwk5BB1JgnemiDQkQoHJwfotEk8I6G1p+XYvKfiw='. The resource has been blocked.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are not trying to use `ember server` in a debugging mode?  You have built the app (with `ember build`)?  When you open the browser, what URL are you using?  Port 3000?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Steve. I'm new to the node ecosystem. I wanted to get it running locally and start tinkering. Following the directions I've tried http://localhost:3000/

Comment: `ember build` will generate static content that can be served by your application.  It's up to you to package this in a way that everything gets deployed correctly.  So you'll need to setup a static route that points to the ember build so the UI will be served by the application.  The key bit in your "integrity" error is: `The resource has been blocked.`  Once you do `ember build`, you should (by default) have a "dist" folder.  That's what your app needs to serve.

Comment: Another option you could try without changing your setup is starting your server, then running ember server in debug mode: `ember server --proxy=http://localhost:3000`  If that works, then you can work on building your package for deployment.

Comment: I tried 'ember build' but got 'sh.exe": ember: command not found' - any thoughts. I'm using git-bash in win7

Comment: Did you do `npm install -g ember-cli` ?  https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#getting-started

Comment: Yes, I did. details here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919414/set-directory-for-npm

Comment: I can't continue if this discussion gets moved to chat, that url is blocked by my employer's proxy.  Try running `npm config ls` and see what you have for `prefix`.  That folder should be in your path and it should contain `ember.cmd`.