# Set directory for NPM

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm

I'm working with git-bash on win 7. I want to develop an ember project and I am working on a thumb drive. I have installed node on my E drive and added the path to the env vars.

```
 $ npm install -g ember-cli
  C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\ember -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember
  C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\� -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember
  + ember-cli@2.16.2
  updated 553 packages in 89.25s

  $ which npm
  /e/nodejs/npm

  $ which node
  /e/nodejs/node

  $ ember build
  sh.exe": ember: command not found
```

So I think whats happening is that npm is installing the packages on the c drive. I need to set a folder on my e drive, to make this portable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this by configuring the npm `prefix` setting:

```
npm config set prefix e:\some\path\on\e
```

This could be done globally or on a per-project basis by modifying the project's `.npmrc` file.

Go to the folder with your `package.json` and run `npm config ls` to see your effective npm config.

See the [npm docs for global settings](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#global)