# No ember-cli-build.js found

Tags: node.js, windows, ember.js

[image]

I'm trying run an Ember project locally : https://github.com/cosmicjs/ember-real-estate-website?files=1.  I'm using pycharm 2017 using git-bash as my terminal in win7. I have npm , node  and ember installed . In pycharm my project looks like the screenshot.

I've been advised to build the project ([Emberjs: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916054/emberjs-failed-to-find-a-valid-digest-in-the-integrity-attribute) , although this is not discussed in the instructions):

```
$ ember build

Running without permission to symlink will degrade build performance.
See http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#windows for details.

- BuildingNo ember-cli-build.js found.
```

You can see the file in the screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you running `ember build` from the `cosmic-real-estate` folder?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm using the project root

Comment: I switched to the cosmic-real-estate folder. Now the build is failing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937116/ember-build-failed