# Ember build failed

Tags: node.js, ember.js

[image]

I'm trying run an Ember project locally : https://github.com/cosmicjs/ember-real-estate-website?files=1.  I'm using pycharm 2017 using git-bash as my terminal in win7. I have npm , node  and ember installed . In pycharm my project looks like the screenshot.

After switching to the cosmic-real-estate folder:

```
  $ ember build

  Running without permission to symlink will degrade build performance.
  See http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#windows for details.

  cleaning up...
  Build failed.
  The Broccoli Plugin: [Funnel: Funnel: index.html] failed with:
  Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\app' -> 'e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\tmp\funnel-input_base_path-ZStiRJkX.tmp'
      at Error (native)
      at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:1069:18)
      at symlinkWindows (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:123:18)
      at symlinkOrCopySync (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:63:5)
      at e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\read_compat.js:86:11
      at tryCatch (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:539:12)
      at invokeCallback (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:554:13)
      at publish (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:522:7)
      at flush (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2414:5)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)

  The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
      at Funnel.Plugin (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
      at new Funnel (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:58:10)
      at EmberApp._rawAppIndex (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:694:12)
      at EmberApp.index (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:678:20)
      at EmberApp.toArray (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1661:12)
      at EmberApp.toTree (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1684:38)
      at module.exports (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\ember-cli-build.js:26:14)
      at Builder.setupBroccoliBuilder (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:56:19)
      at new Builder (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:30:10)
      at BuildTask.run (e:\ember-real-estate-website\cosmic-real-estate\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\build.js:15:19)
```

There is a new node_modules folder visible as well:

[image]

How can I get this working?

Comment: try to run ember build from an administrator shell.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you are not running in admin mode.  Run your shell with "Run as Administrator..."

Comment: I'll give it a try. - http://blog.sirhamy.com/windows-10-how-to-run-git-bash-as-administrator/

Comment: Sorry guys I ran the build command from powershell with admin rights. I'm getting the same error