# Ember: the brocolli plugin failed with quickstart

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, ember.js

[image]

I'm trying run the ember quickstart at https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/getting-started/quick-start/ .  I'm using pycharm 2017 using git-bash as my terminal in win7. I have npm , node  and ember installed . In pycharm my project looks like the screenshot. I'm running everything on a USB key (E:) portably.

My portable node folder at E:nodejs looks like:

[image]

I have set the npm prefix to

```
$ npm config set prefix E:/nodejs
```

Following the directions I have:

```
$ ember serve

Running without permission to symlink will degrade build performance.
See http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#windows for details.

The Broccoli Plugin: [ConfigReplace] failed with:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\app' -> 'E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\tmp\funnel-input_base_path-Vke3ntid.tmp'
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:961:18)
    at symlinkWindows (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:123:18)
    at symlinkOrCopySync (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:63:5)
    at E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\read_compat.js:86:11
    at tryCatch (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:13)
    at publish (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:508:7)
    at flush (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at ConfigReplace.Plugin (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
    at new ConfigReplace (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\broccoli-config-replace\index.js:13:10)
    at EmberApp.index (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:756:12)
    at EmberApp.toArray (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1784:12)
    at EmberApp.toTree (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1809:32)
    at module.exports (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\ember-cli-build.js:24:14)
    at Builder.setupBroccoliBuilder (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:56:19)
    at new Builder (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:30:10)
    at ServeTask.run (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:24:55)
    at Promise.resolve.then (E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:243:46)
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: According to `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\app' -> 'E:\ENVS\js\ember-quickstart\tmp\funnel-input_base_path-Vke3ntid.tmp'`, the build pipeline is trying to symlink a file and you do not have permissions to do so.

Comment: Unless I'm doing it wrong I tried that with no luck - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937116/ember-build-failed

Comment: I also just turned on win10 dev mode (where I have admin privileges). I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure how to set the SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE flag or if I need to.

Comment: Did you try with starting `git-bash` as administrator?

Comment: I did try that, but I'm not sure it worked. I right clicked on the link to git bash and selected 'run as admin'. I then tried it with powershell the same way. Same result